# setTimeout displaying the time left before reloading a div - AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout

I am doing a script to retry a AJAX script in 7 seconds after it failed to load.
Is there a way to display the timeleft in setTimeout?

this is my base script:

```
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'messageContent.php',
        timeout: 1000,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#chatBox").html(data);
            document.getElementById('messages').scrollTop = document.getElementById('messages').scrollHeight;
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var d = document.getElementById("loadcon");
            d.innerHTML = '<div class="loadingAnimation"><h3 class="status">Reconnecting...</h3></div>';
            setTimeout (update, 7000);
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: It will probably be accurate enough to use setInteval and let it run for 7 iterations or until the time has expired (save a date object and compare to current time vs 7000).

Comment: You would have to run another timer on a shorter interval in order to be able to do some sort of countdown.  You can save the time when you started the first timer and on the second timer, just do a calculate for how much time is left and display it.   Or, you can just use one repeating timer on a shorter interval and count how many times it fires before you trigger your update (e.g. update the countdown every second and after 7 updates, then call your update).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a function to do the timer and call it on your handler

like this:

```
 function startCounter(timeLeft) {
      if (timeLeft > 0) {

        ..display timeLeft

       setTimeout (function() {startCounter(timeLeft-1); }, 1000);
       }
      else{

        ..your function to retry

       }
     }
```

hope that helps :)

Comment: it works, thank you.. but I encounter another problem :( the counter is going crazy if update() is triggered again before it finishes the last counter. Still on understanding this new problem